# Study: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sin(\sin n))^n$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n \sin (x^n)}{n + x^{2n}}$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ \sin (x^n)}{(1+x)^n} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. 
I have to study the convergence of the following three series:

- 1. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sin(\sin n))^n$$
- 2. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n \sin (x^n)}{n + x^{2n}}$$
- 3. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ \sin (x^n)}{(1+x)^n} $$

I'm completely stumped by the first one. For the second and the third I've tried to study the absolute convergence by using root and ratio tests, but with no good results. I've also try to compare the series number **3** with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(|1+x|)^n}$, but again no results.

Could you help me?

Comment: @Farnight Yes: $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

For (1), we have $\sin n \in [-1, 1]$ and since $\sin$ is increasing on $[-1, 1]$ we have $\sin \sin n \in [-\sin 1, \sin 1]$ (note too that $0 \leq \sin 1 \leq 1$).

For (2), applying the Comparison and Ratio Tests gives that the series converges for $|x| > 1$ (noting that for particular negative values of $x$ certain terms in the series do not exist for division-by-zero reasons).

For (3), as in (2), again applying the Comparison and Ratio Tests gives converges for a certain set of $x$ values.

Comment: Then, is it sure that the root test is satisfied (that is, $\sin \sin n$ is strictly less than $1$)? If yes (as it seems) why?

Comment: Could you please add more details? Unfortunately, as the answer is, it gives me no help since I've actually already tried these tests with no results.

Comment: It's not enough that $\sin \sin n$ is strictly less than $n$ for each $n$ (it's possible for a sequence to have ratios all less than $1$ but converging to $1$); it *is* enough that $|\sin \sin n| \leq C$ for some constant $C < 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: For (1), $|\sin \sin n| \leq \sin 1$, so the series is bounded by $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (\sin 1)^n$, and this latter series converges by the Ratio Test (the ratio is $\sin 1 < 1$).

Comment: But again, how do you know (apart from calculations with electronic calculator) that $\sin 1 < 1$ and not $\sin 1 = 1$ (which would yield no result)? Also, as I've written in the comment above, would you mind adding more details for (2) and (3)?

Comment: @mathlearner That's because $0<1<\pi/2$

Comment: @Farnight Oh, I see now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Since (1) the angle of an anticlockwise quarter-turn is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and (2) $0 < 1 < \frac{\pi}{2}$, this follows more or less from the usual unit circle definition of $\sin$. I'll leave it to someone else inclined to add more details for the hints for (2)-(3).

Comment: @Farnight, Would you be so kind to expand on Travis work for problems (2) and (3) to show exactly what to do (so that I realize where I got wrong)?

Answer (score 0):

The second one is simple, if $|x|<1$, use the fact that: $\sin x^n\approx x^n$. And if $|x|>1$, then $|\sin x^n|<1$ and you only need to look at the denominator

---

For the third one, we have $$\sum \frac{\sin(x^n)}{(1+x)^n}\leq\sum \frac{1}{|1+x|^n}<\infty$$
And $$\sum \frac{\sin(x^n)}{(1+x)^n}\leq\sum \left|\frac{x}{1+x}\right|^n<\infty$$

So if $|1+x|>1$ or $\left|\frac{1+x}{x}\right|>1$, then the sum converges. This gives us that the sum converges for $x>-1/2$ and for $x<-2$.
For $-1<x<-1/2$:
$$\frac{\sin(x^n)}{(1+x)^n}\approx\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^n \tag{$\sin(x)\approx_{x\to 0} x$}$$

which doesn't tend to $0$, so the series diverges ($\left|\frac{x}{1+x}\right|>1$).

The only remaining case is $-2\leq x<-1$. In this case $|1+x|\leq 1$.
So we only need to show that $\sin x^n$ doesn't tend to $0$, when $1<x<2$. But this doesn't seem like an easy task. I'll post another answer if I come up with anything.